Estimators for contaminated data
Say we are working with a continuous probability distribution. This distribution follows the huber contamination model. Meaning there are $1-\epsilon$ percent of observations folowing a normal distribution centered in $\mu > 0 $, and the rest have an arbitrary cdf :
$$F = (1- \epsilon) \cdot \Phi_{\mu,\sigma} + \epsilon \cdot H$$
What properties would a good estimator of the mean $\mu$ satisfy. Suppose we know that value of $\sigma$.
Would you use M-estimators ? If yes what kind ? If not then what other family of estimators would work ? I thought of the following estimator
$$ T =\underset{t \in \mathbb{R}}{\mathrm{argmax}} \int_0 ^{\infty}  min(f(x), \varphi_{t,\sigma}(x))dx$$
The intuition of the above estimator is: finding the largest normal distribution of size $1-\epsilon$ that lies under the density curve of all observations. Thus we slide a kernel (here a normal distribution), and at each mean t, we see if there are at least $1-\epsilon$ percent of observations normally distributed around t.
I've never seen this estimator and thus have no clue if its good, or if I'm looking too far. The goal is to have it be robust but precise.
Thanks !
